# How can I set the row height for a defined name (range) in Spreadsheet Light?

Tags: c#, excel-interop, named-ranges, spreadsheetlight

I am trying to convert Excel Interop code to Spreadsheet Light. The legacy Interop code I want to emulate is:

```
var columnHeaderRowRange = _xlSheetFillRateByDistributorByCustomer.Range[
    _xlSheetFillRateByDistributorByCustomer.Cells[1, 1],
    _xlSheetFillRateByDistributorByCustomer.Cells[1, 16]];
columnHeaderRowRange.Interior.Color = Color.LightBlue;
columnHeaderRowRange.RowHeight = 12;
columnHeaderRowRange.Font.Bold = true;
columnHeaderRowRange.Font.Size = 11;
```

I'm creating a defined name (new designation, or Spreadsheet Light's description, of a range) like so, in Spreadsheet Light-ese:

```
SLDocument sl;
. . .
sl.SetDefinedName("columnHeaderRowRange", "Sheet1!$A$1:$P$4");
```

I would think I could set the row height for the range something like this:

```
sl.SetRowHeight("columnHeaderRowRange", 12);
```

...but that doesn't work; the first arg must be an int (row index).

So I thought maybe I could add it to a style that I could then apply to the defined name:

```
SLStyle headerStyle = sl.CreateStyle();
```

..and then apply that style to the defined name like so:

```
sl.SetCellStyle("columnHeaderRowRange", headerStyle); // Remember Merle Haggard!
```

...but I see no properties in SLStyle that will allow me to do that, either.

How can I control the height of all the rows within a defined name?

I think I have everything from the Excel Interop range converted over besides that in my style:

```
headerStyle.Fill.SetPattern(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.
    Spreadsheet.PatternValues.Solid, Color.Black, Color.LightBlue);
headerStyle.Font.Bold = true;
headerStyle.Font.FontSize = 12;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing could effectively be accomplished via:

```
sl.SetRowHeight(1, 4, 12);
```

...or if you want the range to run through the last row added:

```
var stats = sl.GetWorksheetStatistics();
var rowcount = stats.NumberOfRows;
sl.SetRowHeight(1, rowcount, 12);
```

Although not being able to use a Range for some things with Spreadsheet Light, it seems pretty easy using values available via the GetWorksheetStatistics() method to accomplish handy tasks such as fit every row and column:

```
SLWorksheetStatistics wsstats = sl.GetWorksheetStatistics();
int rowCount = wsstats.NumberOfRows;
int colCount = wsstats.NumberOfColumns;

sl.AutoFitRow(1, rowCount);
sl.AutoFitColumn(1, colCount);
```

Of course, the values provided a defined name could be used, too, in suchlike instances:

```
sl.SetDefinedName("grandTotalRowRange",
        string.Format("Sheet1!${0}${1}:${2}${3}", 
            GetExcelTextColumnName(SHORTNAME_BYDCBYLOC_COL),
            rowToPopulate,
            GetExcelTextColumnName(QTYSHIPPED_BYDCBYLOC_COL),
            rowToPopulate)
        );

sl.AutoFitRow(rowToPopulate, rowToPopulate); // autofit the one row
sl.AutoFitColumn(SHORTNAME_BYDCBYLOC_COL, QTYSHIPPED_BYDCBYLOC_COL); // autofit the subset of columns
```